# ExtJS 4.1.1 Form returns empty values

Tags: extjs

http://jsfiddle.net/ycuk/YeSp7/3/
insert some text in fields on form and click on Add button.
(onCreatePls or onSavePls method)

```
firebug:
JSON
pls_id: 0
pls_index: ""
pls_name: ""

{"pls_id":0,"pls_name":"","pls_index":""}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: add 'name' property to the form fields. The name property will have value 'pls_name' and 'pls_index'. By this the value will get retrieved properly. The problem have in your code is with updating the retrieved value to the store.

Comment: thx, Jai! how can i close this ask?

Comment: click on edit below your question and modify the title to [Closed]